# Implementation of converting quads into triangles in 3D space

Tags: opengl, 3d, blender

From what I understand, OpenGL typically converts quads into triangles before drawing them, as mentioned on OpenGL's [wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Quads). It is also stated that "*The four vertices are expected to be coplanar; failure to do so can lead to undefined results*".

From my testing non-coplanar quads will be drawn as two triangles with one of the quad's diagonal used as a shared edge between the two triangles.

**How is it determined which one of the two diagonals will be used?** (therefore which pair of triangles will be used)? I tested the behavior in blender as well and it seems to depend on proportions of the quad (shown in [Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib7jL.png) and [Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOaBM.png)).

From what I found on the Internet the implementation doesn't depends on OpenGL (sources: [Generating triangles from a square grid](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45044/generating-triangles-from-a-square-grid), [Quad from non-planar vertices](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/320268-quad-from-non-planar-vertices/3061180/)), but then I'm a bit confused what does it actually depends on. Is there some kind of standard on what algorithm to use, or is it all wild west and everybody does it differently?

Comment: The blender results have nothing to do with OpenGL. Even if Blender uses OpenGL rendering, there is a conversion step between blender internal datastructures (which supports polygons of arbitrary vertex count) to Triangles which happens completely independent of OpenGL.

Comment: For OpenGL: As the spec states, having quads like that "can lead to undefined results". It's up to each OpenGL implementation what it does with such a quad. It might render it choosing any diagonal it likes, it might completely ignore it. It could behave differently on different GPUs or even in different driver versions on the same GPU. There is no way to know in advance what will happen.